# How to write a code in a specific line?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I need help. I don't know how to delete an item from the listbox by double click the item.

I have just started like 1 hour ago so I don't have code that can help.

I didn't find anything on internet that could help me. If you know how to do this or a tutorial please comment that.

**UPDATE 1**
This is all the code I have:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;


namespace Scratch
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        //close form
        private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        //btnWhenClicked
        private void btnWhenStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ListItemsBox.Items.Add("When Start");
            btnWhenStart.Hide();
            string path = @"C:\Users\Estagio\Desktop\MyTest.txt";

            //Create And Write File
            if (!File.Exists(path))
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine("using System;");
                }
            }


        }

        //delete ListItemsBox Selected Item
        private void ListItemsBox_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

I don't know if this can help you:

**Update2**
I know there is a double click event I just don't know how to delete an item when double click.

**Update3**
I can't do more questions so I ask here.

How can I write a text in specific line like this code?

Exp:

```
private void btnStringEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
         ListItemsBox.Items.Add("When Start");
                    btnWhenStart.Hide();
                    string path = @"C:\MyTest.txt";

                    if (!File.Exists(path))
                    {
                        using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
                        {
                            sw.WriteLine("line1");
    sw.WriteLine("line2");
    sw.WriteLine("line4");
                        }
                    }
}
```

Then I have another:

```
private void btnAnotherEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
         ListItemsBox.Items.Add("When Start");
                    btnWhenStart.Hide();
                    string path = @"C:\MyTest.txt";

                    if (!File.Exists(path))
                    {
                        using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
                        {
                          //Here I want some code that put something   //between line2 and line 4
                        }
                    }
      }
```

How can I do it?

Comment: WPF, ASP.NET or Winforms? Also, what have you tried so far and where are you getting stuck?

Comment: Add some relevant code...

Comment: @EJoshuaS the tag clear says it's `c#`

Comment: Well, start by breaking down what you want to do. Look at the listbox, what options do you have .. if you look some will sound more useful to this task than others, try them, see what they do..  The world will not implode if it doesnt work the way you hoped.  Come back here when you have code, and ask specific questions

Comment: Is there not a listbox double click event you can hook into....

Comment: @jonju WPF, ASP.NET and Winforms all have that control, it's not clear which he's using. Just tagging this as "C#" isn't nearly specific enough.

Comment: @CallumLinington yes but i dont know how to delet the iteam when doule click

Comment: I'm guessing WinForms. Look at this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousedoubleclick(v=vs.110).aspx there is a double click event. Also when you double click it, you'll be able to see which item is selected...

Comment: @jonju i am using winform c#

Comment: Here from that same page `listBox1.SelectedIndices[0]` gets you the list of selected items indexes. So you can use that to remove from the items you give it. Its an array because you can set it to select more that one!

Comment: @CallumLinington Finaly someone tell me what i want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

```
private void ListItemsBox_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e){
    DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete this item?",
                                "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, 
                                MessageBoxIcon.Warning,MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2);
    if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        ListItemsBox.Items.Remove(ListItemsBox.SelectedItem);
    }
    else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Check the solution for you 3rd requirement

Answer (score 0):

A similar question like this has been asked: 
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8cabccca-f2b9-40c4-9cf5-89cbcbc06f03/remove-selected-items-from-listbox-when-pressed-delete-button?forum=csharplanguage

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to delete 1 item at a specific index use:

```
listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(YOUR INDEX);
```